# Embedding Instagram via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, embed, instagram, instagram-api

We are using Instagram's oEmbed-API to get embed codes. However, we do not want to solely rely on that API and generate embed codes ourselves. The embed code as provided by the API (or the website) includes a lot of html, css image data and text content, all of that already has to be there before you can work the embed js on it. This is a problem because we cannot implement a generic embed code but have to know the instagram content for each photo or video in advance.

My question is: Ist there a generic embed code, something like this, for instagram?

```
<script async defer=\"defer\" src=\"//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"></script>
<script>instgrm.Embeds.genenerate('some instragram ID for instance')<script/>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `iframe` to embed like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BFKjVxkBsCC/embed" width="400" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

adding `/embed` to instagram post URL will give you image that can be embedded

adding `/embed/captioned` will add caption to the image

Here is link to easily generate embed code: https://www.picodash.com/instagram/embed#https://www.instagram.com/p/BFKjVxkBsCC/

Comment: Thanks but iFrames are not an option for us, they are slow in both loading and rendering performance and are often a pain to use esp. on mobile when swiping through content.

Comment: the script embed you get from instgram also uses iframe eventually. Other option is to use Instagram API and get image link and load as <img>, but u will need to authenticate and get access_token and make calls:https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_by_shortcode